# LINQ method to return values as a single object including a nested array

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Goal: Returning a single object of `sum` and a list of details.
`{ Sum: 1, [ { Amount: 2, Hex: '#123456' }, { Amount: 1, Hex: '#123456' } ] }`

Using the below, I cannot achieve the goal:

```
    var data = (await _context.Users
        .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
        .SelectMany(ue => ue.Expenses)
        .Where(ue => ue.CreatedOn.Date <= insightsFilter.To.Value.Date 
            && ue.CreatedOn.Date >= insightsFilter.From.Value.Date)
        .Include(ue => ue.UserExpenses)
        .Include(e => e.Category)
        .ToListAsync());
    
    var response = data.Select(e => new GetCategoriesDto {
        Sum = e.UserExpenses.Sum(ue => ue.Amount),
        Data = data.GroupBy(e => e.Category.Name.ToLower())
            .Select(cl => new GetDetailsDto {
                    Hex = "#123456"
            }).ToList()
    });
```

The output is a single array as such:

```
{ Sum: 3, Data: [  { Sum: 2, Amount: 2, Hex: '#123456' }, { Sum: 1, Amount: 1, Hex: '#123456' } ] }
```

Where Sum is repeated instead of being on top of the JSON object with a value of 2 + 1 = 3.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong... Thanks!

Data is as follows:

```
- Users
 -- UserExpenses (Junction) - Contains Amount value.
  -- Expenses - Contains Category value.


    public class Expense
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public List<UserExpenseJunction> UserExpenses { get; set; } = new List<UserExpenseJunction>();
    }

    public class  UserExpenseJunction {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int ExpenseId { get; set; }
        public Expense Expense { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
}


    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public IList<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
        public IList<UserExpenseJunction> UserExpenses { get; set; }
        public bool Verified { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Input samples are welcome

Comment: Could you please provide sample input as valid C# code, including class definitions, and also, if possible, the expected output as a C# literal?

Comment: What is `ue.Expenses`? If it's a collection of Expenses your model is wrong. First priority is to get the model right, then the query.

Comment: @GertArnold Why so? Please check the update with the classes.

Comment: @GertArnold Added (A user created an expense, but the same expense can have a list of users - contributors to that expense)

Comment: The reference as one to many is there to determine which user created the expense. The UserExpenses Junction is there to add other users who can contribute to the expense, should the one to many reference not be there?

Comment: You know your business, but I think you should use the many-to-many relationship as source of your query, because you need the amounts.

Comment: Another thing that's unclear: you group by `Category.Name` but the name of the group is `Sum` with an integer value. It's not really clear what you want.

Comment: Exactly, the sum should be the total sum of amounts for all categories. So you'd have two expenses under 'Gift' category with a sum of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a `Select` on your list so of course it will create a `GetCategoriesDto` for each item the list.

you need to do the sum as a separate item so I think something like this should work (I haven't tried it)

```
 var response = new {
       Sum = data.Select(e => e.UserExpenses.Sum(g => g.Amount)).Sum(),
       data.Select(e => new GetCategoriesDto {
           Data = data.GroupBy(e => e.Category.Name.ToLower())
            .Select(cl => new GetDetailsDto {
                    Amount = cl.Amount.Sum(),
                    Hex = "#123456"
            }).ToArray()
    });
```

It's a little guess by me because you have some missing code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`response` is a List, because you created it as a List: `var response = data.Select(...).ToList()`.


Create the `reponse` as:

```
var response = new GetCategoriesDto 
{
  //Sum = sum of amounts, ...
}
```